# Getting ValueError from Extracting Links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am extracting the url links from a Wiki page and coming up with an "ValueError" when it tries to parse for certain links. I am looking for a way to ignore the errors or fix the issue. It seems that when the loop is extracting the links, it runs into links that it does not recognize as a link and traceback.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import ssl
import re

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
url = input("Enter First Link: ")
if len(url)<1:   url = "https://www.bing.com/search?q=k+means+wiki&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IENAD2"

position = 18
process = 7

#to repeat 18 times#
for i in range(process):
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    tags = soup('a')
    count = 0
    for tag in tags:
        count = count +1
        #make it stop at position 3#
        if count>position:
            break
        url = tag.get('href', None)

        print(url)
```

Raises:

```
ValueError      Traceback (most recent call last)

ValueError: unknown url type: '/search?q=Cluster+analysis%20wikipedia&FORM=WIKIRE'
```

Answer (score 1):

The url that it is encountering has no schema or domain. It is a relative url meaning it needs to be appended to the current page url in order to go to it.  urls usually start with schema://domain.domain like in `https://www.facebook.com`.  If you check your urls to be sure they contain the schema and domain then attach them if they are missing then you will avoid this error.

An example:

`/search?q=stack+overflow`

might be a relative url for a search on google for stack overflow.

To reconstruct the full url you just add `https://www.google.com` to the beginning and it becomes an actual search link `https://www.google.com/search?q=stack+overflow`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the error is because that isn't a valid link. You could try prepending "https://bing.com" to the beginning of the URL, or by catching the errors.

To catch the error:

```
try:
    url = tag.get('href', None)
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid URL")
```

To prepend the URL:

```
url = 'https://bing.com' + url
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#errors-and-exceptions

see python documentation for errors and exceptions.

you can put it in the loop:

```
for i in range(process):
    try:
        "line of code causes the problem"
    except ValueError:
        print("invalid url")
```

hope that helps.